# Feedly on Chrome loads in incognito mode but not otherwise even with all extensions disabled

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, rss

Feedly isn't loading. When I open Feedly in Chrome, I get the message:

> Is feedly blocked?
>   Feedly is not able to load. It is probably because one of your extensions is blocking it. If you run Adblock, HTTPSEverywhere, Awesome screenshot etc.. please make sure that feedly.com is white listed.

Feedly loads fine in incognito mode. I've disabled all extensions and non-incognito mode still has this problem.

I'm running Chrome 57.0.2987.110 on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry to hear this. If it works fine in incognito, please clear you cache and try again. It'll be either cache issue or extension one.